# FileNotFoundError when trying to use Pydub to split audio segments

Tags: pydub

I am trying to use pydub to split audio into evenly spaced segments. Right now I can't seem to even get it to read the audio file. I'm using Jupyter notebook through Anaconda. The solutions from the other topic on this did not help ([How to fix FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified with AudioSegment.from_mp3()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669182/how-to-fix-filenotfounderror-winerror-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-speci))

I have:

- added libav to PATH
- specified where the ffmpeg exe file is, and also installed through conda
- tried running it from command prompt
- tried with and without the AudioSegment.converter line, as well as with and without AudioSegment.ffmpeg
- tried with AudioSegment.from_file and .from_mp3

Would appreciate some help.

```
import pydub
import math

from pydub import AudioSegment
pydub.AudioSegment.converter = r'C:\Users\M\Desktop\Pydub\ffmpeg.exe'

AudioName = 'Abc' #Name of audio (string)
AudioImported = AudioSegment.from_mp3(r'C:\Users\M\Desktop\Pydub\Abc.mp3')
AudioLength = AudioImported.duration_seconds

Interval = input('Clip length (seconds):') #Length of each clip in seconds
NumClips = math.floor(AudioLength / Interval)

t1 = 0
for i in range(1,  NumClips):
    t2 = t1 + i*1000
    Clip = AudioImported[t1:t2]
    ClipName = AudioName + 'i' + '.mp3'
    Clip.export(ClipName, format='mp3')
    t1 = t2
```

Edit: Issue resolved itself somehow. Last thing I did was install ffmpeg thorugh conda, but I guess it took a while to kick in.

Also apparently this function is right in the documentation that I missed:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
sound = AudioSegment.from_file("/path/to/sound.wav", format="wav")

# split sound in 5-second slices and export
for i, chunk in enumerate(sound[::5000]):
  with open("sound-%s.mp3" % i, "wb") as f:
    chunk.export(f, format="mp3")
```

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback error?

Comment: @ewong I don't know what changed, but it seems to be working now. The last thing I did was installing ffmpeg through conda. I guess it needed a few minutes to kick in? I dunno. Thanks for your concern anyway. Also the function that I was making was actually right in the documentation (slice), I've updated that in the OP.

Comment: if work now afther the conda solution you should close that question